# PHP HTML Contact us form issue

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using html ( bootstrap4) contact us page  and trying to make it dynamic . server test ok with the php test script using pear mail.

But issue when trying to  make dynamic and calling filed out put in email its not working

Can any one review below php script and tell me where is issue

HOW can I call here this part : $email_subject ? email body ? and email message ?

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="test.php">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
      <input type="text" name="Full_Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
    </div>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
    </div>
    <!-- subject -->
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">

      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="subject *" required="required" data-error="Valid subject is required.">
    </div>
    <!-- Message -->
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message  *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <div class="col-12 text-right">
      <input type="submit" class=" form-control btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- Email -->
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2"> <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required."> </div>
```

---

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT);

require_once "Mail/Mail-1.4.1/Mail.php";
$name = $_POST["Full_Name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$host = "*******"; <!--i will use my hosting server url-->
$username = "*******"; <!--i will use my email-->
$password = "*****";  <!--i will use here my email pss-->
$port = "2525";
$to = "******";  <!--i will use the email here-->
$email_from = "*****";  <!--how to call email from here by input that i defined above in php file->
$email_subject = "******" ; <!--how to call sujectl from here by input that i defined above in php file->
$email_body = "*****";    <!--how to call message from here by input that i defined above in php file->
$email_address = "*****";   

$headers = array ('From' => $email, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject, 'Message' => $message, Reply-To' => $email_address);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no JS here. Removed the tag. Please do not tag-spam

Comment: Don't you just mean: `$email_from = $email;` etc? where $email is the cleaned address you got from `$_POST["email"];`

Comment: i have defined that like the way you are talking "$email_from = $email;" but  not getting any email and even my contact us page  after submit  trun white  no  message displaying and not receiving inbox .. but when i am using the test script  in place of  $email_form = "xyg@gmail.com " and same with dummy text  for other field form working and receiving email inbox  dont know what the issue.

Comment: Please show the form. Perhaps you do not POST it or you use ID and not NAME

Comment: <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="test.php">
<div class="row">
<!-- Name -->
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
<input type="text" name="Full_Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
            </div>
<!-- Email -->
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
</div>

Comment: I updated your question. You have only half a form there

Comment: i have updated the form above for review

Comment: No errors in the server logs?

Comment: No error getting a white blank page  only ..  now can you tell me my script is  correct based on the  html form ?
Also -- i dont know when i am using the test script here with same form its working. but in actual dynamic turn its not working

Comment: @mplungjan, thank you for  supporting here and trying to resolve the issue . i  found the error  and now its working

Comment: Great. Feel free to delete the question. What was the error btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully reading the code and  optimized slightly its working pefrectly and here i am pasting it.. might it be helpful for some one facing the same issue with html/php/pear

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT);
require_once "Mail/Mail-1.4.1/Mail.php";
$name = $_POST["Full_Name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$host = "mail.example.com"; 
$username = "xyz@example.com";
$password = "abc";
$port = "25";
$to = "xyz@example.com";
$reply_to = "xyz@example.com"; 
$headers = array ('From' => $email, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject, 'Reply-To' => $reply_to);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to future readers if you included an explanation of what you've changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a slight revamp of the code which might help, also if you're using gmail to send the email please see the last bit of this article: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216140597-How-do-I-send-PHP-mail-via-SMTP-

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT);

require_once "Mail/Mail-1.4.1/Mail.php";

$name = $_POST["Full_Name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$host = "*******"; <!--i will use my hosting server url-->
$username = "*******"; <!--i will use my email-->
$password = "*****";  <!--i will use here my email pss-->
$port = "2525";

$to = "******";  <!--i will use the email here-->
$reply_to = "*****";   

// Please note the change to the headers
$headers = array ('From' => $email, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject, Reply-To' => $reply_to);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: You mean you just use the posted variables instead of intermediate ones. Why would that improve the non-sending of the email?

Comment: I also changed the headers to the correct format and informed him about the format required if using gmail

Comment: That would be useful to point out. I could not at a glance see what else you had changed

Comment: Jak, sorry no luck with this as well i tried as you said .

Comment: jak , when i was  do test with the same  php script  with same html form its working  but when trying to get a dynamic value in that case  no luck

Comment: Is there any specific error message being shown? If not then I would likely agree with mplungjan that there may be something wrong with the form

Comment: not getting any error message   simply blank white page .    i am not getting why the test script working and throwing email  successfully

Comment: Jak, any idea why test dummy script working on server  but not the customized one  that actually required

Comment: @Jak, thank you for  supporting here and trying to resolve the issue . i  found the error  and now its working for me perfectly .

Comment: Gavy, good to hear that you've got it working. What was the issue in the end? I'll happily update my answer so that others can learn too